# Can I find an expression for this sequence by only knowing the first two and last two terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have the following sum: $1 \cdot n \cdot a_1+2 \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \cdot a_2 \quad+ \quad... \quad+ \quad (n-1) \cdot n \cdot a_{n-1} + n \cdot 1 \cdot a_n$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$

which I want to translate to $\sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot (?) \cdot a_i$

I know beforehand that the first factor in the sum will be the sequence $\quad 1,2,3,...,n-1,n \quad $and therefore I substituted that with $i$, and the third factor will obviously be $a_i$

Is the second factor in the sum uniquely defined or do we need more terms to be able to find it?

Comment: Sorry, isn't $\sum_{i=1}^n i C_n^i a_i$ approptiate for you?

Comment: @PavelKozlov ah yes, sorry, completely flew by my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these terms, it seems to be equal to ${n \choose i}$, which is defined as $\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$. It equals to amount of subsets of size $i$ from a set of $n$ elements. For $i = 1, 2, n-1$, we obtain ${n \choose 1} = {n \choose n - 1} = n$, ${n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.